# How do I change directory to a path containing spaces in cmder on Windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, cmder, cd

I am working with both Docker Quickstart Terminal (Bash) and Cmder on Windows10.

On Bash, to change directory to a path where some folder contains spaces, I usually do:

```
cd "D:\my files\etc\etc"
```

as I launch the same on Cmder, it does not work, but neither it responds with some warning indicating wrong syntax.

I tryed also

```
cd "D:/my files/etc/etc"
```

but nothing.

So how do I change my current directory in Cmder ?

(it has to work with directories having spaces in their names)

Comment: Windows CMD - which will be the command processor in CMDER if it's not PowerShell - generally wants ``\`` rather than `/` in pathnames.

Comment: I tryed both \ and /

Comment: Also, `cd` will not change your current _drive_, only the directory on the specified drive. If your current path is `C:\Users\Foo\Documents` and you type `CD D:\Bar\Quux`, your current directory will still be `C:\Users\Foo\Documents`; you will have to type `D:` to actually change the drive as well.

Comment: As a general comment regarding CMD - I recommend bookmarking [SS64 on CMD](https://ss64.com/nt/), and if you also use PowerShell, [SS64 on PowerShell](https://ss64.com/ps/) - SS64 is clear, concise, and extensive if not fully complete, as a reference to command lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED

turns out that in Cmder when you want to change directory from one driver to another (e.g. from **C:** to **D:** ), you have to insert a `/d` right after the cd command, where the d probably stands for "driver".

So in my case the solution is:

```
cd /d "D:\my files\etc\etc"
```

and

```
cd /d "D:/my files/etc/etc"
```

works too.

Comment: Urf. Yeah, I forgot about that switch...

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that the quotes don't work, but another approach can be to use a backslash `\` character to escape a space. So for example, instead of:

`cd "D:\my files\etc\etc"`

you could try:

`cd D:/my\ files/etc/etc`.

I'm not sure I agree with Jeff's point that CMD prefers one slash over another, since my understanding was that Windows is fine with either and Unix-based systems require forward slashes.

Comment: Windows is fine with either _programmatically_ - that is, in a program you write in e.g., C#, you can use paths with either `/` or ``\`` - but the command processor CMD defaults to using `/` as the switch character, equivalent to the *ix `-`. Recent Windows _seems_ to use `-` and `/` interchangeably as the switch character in most cases, but it's not behavior you can or should count on because some legacy command-line programs may not have been written to accommodate this.

Comment: Good to know, thank you for clearing that up.